# Сообщение с рассылки отправляется только мне. Python aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть база данных и файл который с ней работает(https://pastebin.com/MBTJGphg). Дальше вот часть кода из bot.py которая отвечает за подписку(https://pastebin.com/v3zuB5ev). Все это 100% работает т.к. брал из видео-урока и все айдишники сохраняются в db.db . Дальше идут уже мои каракули

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['special'])
async def notify_users(message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'ало')
```

Я добавил бота в беседу и попросил друга подписаться на рассылку. Я перезагрузил бота его айдишник остался в базе. Дальше когда я его включил и написал команду /special именно от бота мне пришло сообщение "ало"а другу нет.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код отправляет сообщение только вам, так как `message.from_user.id` принимает id пользователя, отправившего сообщение.

Для того, чтобы отправлять сообщения всем пользователям, подписанным на рассылку, вы можете использовать перебор массива из id пользователей (в примере - `user_ids`) при помощи цикла `for`.

Пример:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['special'])
async def notify_users(message: types.Message):
    for user_id in user_ids:
        await bot.send_message(user_id, 'ало')
```

Comment: `id` в питоне это функция, лучше использовать другое имя

Comment: сейчас исправлю